# "The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response." issue while downloading a published package from SFTP server to target server

Tags: powershell, sftp, winrm

I have implemented CI/CD using TFS2105. I have published the build artifacts to sftp server. In release pipeline i am downloading that build package form sftp server. At this time it is getting failed saying:

```
[error]The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop:
Processing data from remote server "server_name" failed with the following error message:
The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response.  A provider in the host process may have behaved improperly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

In Ps code i had below code to download the package.

```
Get-SFTPFile ($sftpSession).SessionId -RemoteFile $_.FullName -LocalPath $targetDir -Overwrite
Start-Sleep -s 5
# disconnect SSH session
```

Since my package zip was 130MB in size, so during publish i broke into small zip files.

I have seen most of the people says increase the  'MaxMemoryPerShellMB' value. I have increased the value on sftp server as well as on my local server target server to 512MB. Even in my local it is 4096MB. 
I ran the `WinRM quickconfig` and `WinRM enumerate` and here it is the value on my target machine.

I am looking into these issue since long time. please help. Thanks In advance.